# Send multiple file into solr

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing

I want to sending multiple files to solr using curl.How i can do it ?

I can done with only one file with command for example:

> curl
>   "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=paas2&commit=true"
>   -F "file=@cloud.pdf"

Anyone can help me,

Tks

Answer (score 1):

The api does not support passing multiple files for extraction.
Usually the last file will be the only one thats gets uploaded and added.

You can have individual files indexed as separate entities in Solr.

OR One way to upload multiple files is to zip these files and upload the zip file.
There is one issue with Solr indexing zip files and you can try the [SOLR-2332](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2332) Patch

Comment: Well, How about indexing static folder which content some file without upload using curl ?is it possible ?

Comment: Nope. With Solr you have to upload the files. And with folder you have to iterate and upload it.

Comment: How if i have thousands files and now i have thousands file for indexing ? should i upload them one by one ?

Comment: You can easily create a script to iterate and upload files. So you dont have to do it manually. Also, these files will be individual documents in Solr and not a combined document.

Comment: Let's check my solr on http://indexing.osmosa.net/solr/browse  i have uploaded hundreds file, using curl command like :java -Durl=http://localhost:8906/solr/update/extract?literal.id=PPN -Dtype=text/html -jar post.jar *.htm   But when i try to search with keyword PPN, only one file show on result.How about it ?

Answer (score 1):

i using apache solr 4.0 Beta which have capability to upload multiple file and generate id for each file uploaded using post.jar and It's very helpfull for me.

Let'see on :

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#SimplePostTool_.28post.jar.29

Thanks all :)

my problem have solved :)